# Openni, Android, and PrimeSense Setup

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, openni, primesense

I am trying to develop a simple Android application (running on nexus 10) that will connect to a PrimeSense camera. From my research it seems that Openni is the way to go; however, I'm having a hard time figuring out what I need. When I download the Openni software and install it I get a whole bunch of different files but I'm unable to find a simple explanation of how to do a simple 'hello world' type application:

What openni jars do I need and where can I find them?
How do I configure my Eclipse/Android Studio project to include these jars. 
Are there any other files that I need besides those jars: drivers..?

I just started Android dev and I've never used PrimeSense nor any other 3D scanning cameras so maybe I'm just missing something obvious?

Could someone point me in the right direction? I haven't been able to find anything on the Openni website that would help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a simple tutorial on how to proceed. It's straightforward

http://www.hirotakaster.com/weblog/openframeworks-8-1-and-openni-2-2-on-android-tutorial/